# What is open first in formal languages

Tags: formal-languages, regular-language, regular-expressions

> What is a set of values that come from $(1^*0^*)^*$?

Is it set of any number of combinations of any number of 1 and any number of 0. Like we have 10 inside of brackets and than repeat it as much as you want , mean $101010...$ Or is it a set of words of any length consisting of 1 and 0?

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: It's either $\{0,1\}^*$ or $\{(1^k0^\ell)^m\mid k, \ell, m\in\Bbb N\cup\{0\}\}$ but I'm not sure. It's been too long since I did formal languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$1^*0^*$ is the language consisting of all the words formed by any number of $1$'s followed by any number of $0$'s. (Here "any number of" includes the possibility of none.) So it contains, for example, $11100$ and $10000000$ and $11$ and $0000000$ and the empty word, but not $11001$ nor $01$.

Therefore $(1^*0^*)^*$ consists of all the words you can get by concatenating any (finite) number of words from the language $1^*0^*$ in the preceding paragraph. So, to use my examples from above (in the order I listed them), it would include $1110010000000110000000$.

In fact, since both $0$ and $1$ are in $1^*0^*$, it follows that all words formed from $0$'s and $1$'s are in $(1^*0^*)^*$.  That is, this language is the same as $\{0,1\}^*$.